# How to open JSF page and pass parameter by href link?

Tags: jsf

Now I have one website. I want to provide user one link with one parameter. Then he can access the website and query something according the parameter. I want to the link is `"http://10.182.20.86:8080/webproject/main.xhtml/scenarioid=1234"` etc.

Now I use rest to pass the parameter to Java. But I can't get instance from `FacesContext`. It always returns `null`, when I use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` <s>in Java</s>. Do you know how to implement the function by link with parameter in JSF? Thanks.

Comment: I use rest can pass the parameter. But I don't how to get the current session and FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is null. It's better to provide with link, which is the format of rest call. And I can open the web page after passing the parameter.

Comment: In which class exactly are you trying to grab the request parameter via the current instance of the JSF context? If it's null, then it apparently isn't a JSF managed class and you're currently actually not sitting in the JSF context (i.e. the `FacesServlet` is not invoked in the current request). You should instead use the facility provided by the specific framework whose context you're currently actually sitting in.

Comment: Thanks, Balus. I think you are right. My class is one rest call and it's not one JSF bean. But I add it to faces-config.xml as session bean. I still can't get FacesContext.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I suggest to stop shooting in the dark on Y and just state the concrete functional requirement you're trying to solve on X. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem In the meanwhile, going through a decent book on the separate subjects wouldn't be a bad idea in order to grasp the basic concepts and terminology the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by create one class and it extends HttpServlet. I get the parameter by request and get bean attribute by HttpServletRequest getSession. Now it works. Thanks, Balus.